# wordpress add html to very top of page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header

I am looking to find a solution for the following problem:

Via a plugin i would like to add a black bar to the very top of every page (similar to the wordpress admin bar you can see when you are logged in at wp-admin).

A solution I was looking into was to just add the code via a javascript file and append the html to the header. However this does not sound like the right way to do it. Unfortunately I haven't found any references on google on how to effictively do this the right way.

I was looking into register_my_menus() function but the function description did not promise the desired efforts.

Can anyone point me into the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think javascript would be better to append the html for a admin bar.  If these users aren't affiliated with a wp backend you don't need any wp functions to display the desired links.

Answer (score 1):

Another option ( I would say better then appending with JS ) would be to hook into the wp_footer hook and just create the HTML you need and use a CSS position:fixed; or position:absolute; with top: 0;

Example:

```
// Enqueue styles for top-bar
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/top-bar.css' );
});

// Add HTML for top-bar
add_action( 'wp_footer', function(){
    echo '<div class="top-bar">Some content</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to add a function to your theme's functions.php file

```html
function header_notification()
{   
    echo '<div><strong>Any html goes here</strong></div>';
    
}
add_action('wp_head', 'header_notification');
```